# Ensuring one object's attribute in a collection is true and set the others to false

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have a class with a boolean attribute called, `primary`. I have a uniqueness validation setup to ensure that only one in a collection belonging to a specific restaurant is set to true:

```
validates_uniqueness_of :primary, if: :primary, scope: [:restaurant_id]
```

As of recent I wanted to customize the writer method in a way that it assigns the new value of the current instance while setting it's siblings within the collection to false if the instance is true. Despite this, my tests are failing:

```
 MenuGroup did not properly validate that :primary is case-sensitively
       unique within the scope of :restaurant_id.
         After taking the given MenuGroup, setting its :primary to ‹"an
         arbitrary value"› (read back as ‹true›), and saving it as the existing
         record, then making a new MenuGroup and setting its :primary to a
         different value, ‹true› and its :restaurant_id to a different value,
         ‹nil›, the matcher expected the new MenuGroup to be invalid, but it
         was valid instead.
```

Here's the test:

```
it { should validate_uniqueness_of(:primary).scoped_to([:restaurant_id]) }
```

What am I doing wrong here?

```
class MenuGroup < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :restaurant

  validates_uniqueness_of :primary, if: :primary, scope: [:restaurant_id]

  def primary=(primary)
    if primary?
      MenuGroup
       .where.not(id: self.id)
       .where(restaurant_id: self.restaurant_id).update_all(primary: false)
    end

    write_attribute :primary, primary
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

`if primary?` checks whether the record's `self.primary?` is true.

The `?` makes this a call to the local `primary?` method, generated automatically by ActiveRecord. It's **not** a check of the variable `primary` passed as an argument to the function.

That said, the your validation cannot be tested and doesn't actually do anything.

The whole purpose of your `primary=` setter is to automatically unset the previous `primary` record. Your validation cannot trip because your setter prevents your models from getting into an invalid state.

Your test attempts to set a second `MenuGroup` to `primary = true`, but this act sets `primary = false` on all existing `MenuGroup`s, so the validation runs and passes happily.

Comment: Even after removing the `?` I still get the same error.